# How to save Excel JS add-in authorization token on a Mac (Excel JS add-in)?

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, excel-addins

We’ve tried to implement **log in / authorization  for JS Excel add-in** for Mac.

We've faced with such problem for desktop version.

Where can we store a custom login token for the **desktop JS Excel add-in**? In the desktop version there is no Local storage and there is no access to the file system too.

Could you help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the token give access to something on the server? If so, can it be stored in a cookie?

Comment: Yes, with this token we will check if the user has access to a list of the features.

Question regarding the cookies. Do we have an access to cookies in desktop version of the JS Excel add-in? I thought, that cookies are available for browser version of the add-in only.

Comment: It looks like there is no document object in the desktop version of the Excel JS add-in at all. Am I wrong?

Comment: Regardless of whether the add-in is running in Office on the web (aka Office Online) or on Office on Windows, or Office on Mac, etc., the add-in is a web app and it can use cookies.

Comment: Excel.js has a [Workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/excel/excel.workbook) object rather than a document object. The Common Office JavaScript APIs, which can also be used in Excel add-ins have a [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/office/office.document) object. Both of these are available in all the major platforms, Office on Windows, Office on Mac, and Office on the web.